M.2 install, strange motherboard screw
I have a ASRock x370 killer SLI/AC which has two M.2 slots. I installed the first NVMe SSD no problem with the provided hardware, but the second slot had this weird hex shaped standoff that I am unfamiliar with. I would either need a tiny screw instead of the normal M.2 or a way to remove this. I am not sure what to do. Specifically talking about what is installed at CT 15.

Have you tried just screwing your M.2 down into that standoff using the required M2 screw?

The product's page mentions no differences regarding form factor, only stating "One PCIe Gen3 x4 Ultra M.2 interface that pushes data transfer speeds up to 32Gb/s, and is compatible with ASRock’s U.2 Kit for installing some of the world’s fastest U.2 PCIe Gen3 x4 SSD. The other one supports PCIe Gen2 x2 10Gb/s transfer speed. Both of them support SATA3 6Gb/s M.2 modules."

@Mokubai yes. The screws that came with my motherboard are M3*5Flat and some compatible standoffs. The hex shaped one already there is much smaller, none of the screws I have fit

The image isn't super clear, but are there even threads inside that hex stand-off? I would wonder if this is a manufacturing error. Do you have another of these boards to compare this to?

The inside of the hex is threaded, but not sure what size. I ended up removing that hex standoff. And searching my local hardware store until I found a screw that worked

You will need to purchase another flat head M2x2.5 screw. (It doesn't have to be flat head, but a countersunk head screw would not work; pan head or button head should also be OK, depending on if they might interfere with any heatsink you might add to the drive.)
They are readily available, but it is possible that a longer screw is needed: measure the supplied one as the user manual fails to specify the length of the screw. There should be at least 3 turns of the thread engaged, but also not so many that the screw hits the bottom of the hole - that would be bad and break something.
The hex standoff is so that you can unscrew the standoff and put it into a different hole for a different length SSD - see section 2.9 of the manual. It only needs to be tightened gently. If you are really worried about it undoing itself (it won't), then a tiny drop of Loctite 222 thread locker (or equivalent) would work.

So that hex screw is meant to be moved? I have the hardware to attach my SSD as long as it's safe for me to remove that hex

@KennySexton Yes - see section 2.9 of the manual I linked to in my answer. It only needs to be tightened gently. If you are really worried about it undoing itself (it won't), then a tiny drop of Loctite 222 thread locker would work.
